# How to ignore specific sub-field of an unwrapped field (CSV)

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson2

How do I tell Jackson to skip an unwrapped sub-POJO field so when I parse to CSV, it skips the entire column?

Here's a full code example:

```
public class FooTest {

  class Foo {
    String something = "value";
    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "bar.")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "toBeIgnored" })
    Bar bar;

    public String getSomething() {
      return something;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
      return bar;
    }
  }

  class Bar {
    String toBeIgnored;

    public String getToBeIgnored() {
      return toBeIgnored;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void fooTest() throws IOException {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Foo.class).withHeader();
    ObjectWriter csvWriter = mapper.writer(schema);
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SequenceWriter writer = csvWriter.writeValues(outputStream);

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = new Bar();
    String toBeIgnored = "should not be parsed";
    foo.bar.toBeIgnored = toBeIgnored;
    writer.write(foo);
    String result = outputStream.toString();

    assertThat(result).doesNotContain(toBeIgnored);
    assertThat(result).contains("something");
    assertThat(result).doesNotContain("bar.toBeIgnored");
  }
}
```

**Note that I cannot modify class `Bar` in any ways.**

How can I specify in class `Foo` that I want to ignore `bar.toBeIgnored`?

`JsonIgnoreProperties` is useful skipping the value but not the whole column. Current code will output a CSV with column `bar.toBeIgnored` with an empty value. I simply want to skip this column.

Comment: Mind the missing trailing quotation mark in your annotation.

Comment: @Jeep87c did you find any solution to this? i'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "toBeIgnoredA", "toBeIgnoredB" })`

```
public class ToSerialize {
  @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "toBeUnwrapped")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "toBeIgnoredA", "toBeIgnoredB" })
  public ToBeUnwrapped toBeUnwrapped;
}
```

or (long way) create wrapper class for `ToBeUnwrapped` where you can freely configure your JSON annotations with no actual `ToBeUnwrapped` class touching

Comment: Ok so it partially works. Meaning the value will be ignored but the column toBeUnwrapper.toBeIgnored will be present in the CSV with empty values. Anyway to also ignore the column too so it's not part of the resulting csv file without having to use a wrapper class?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get it with empty - in my tests I did not get it in resulting JSON (and you are talking now about CSV). Perhaps CSV serialization works differently, and I never used it, sorry. Check  `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` on class level or on actual field's level.

Comment: Looks like CSV is different indeed. I'll update my question with a full code example in a sec