# Jackson Mixin's Ignoring a property when using @JsonUnwrapped but only some cases

Tags: jackson, jackson2

With Jackson i'm using Mixin interfaces to Serialize.

Suppose i have a common class used by multiple classes, here the Mixin of that class:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name"})
interface SharedMixin {
    String getId();

    String getName();
}
```

That Mixin is used by multiple Mixin's using @JsonUnwrapped annotation, like the following:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"code", "sharedMixin"})
public interface AnotherMixin {
  String getCode();

  @JsonUnwrapped
  SharedMixin getSharedMixin();
}
```

That works fine, it unwraps all the properties from the SharedMixin Interface. But there's a specific case where i want to ignore one property of the SharedMixin when Unwrapping in the parent Mixin, suppose i want to ignore the name field.
I tried the following but without success.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"otherField", "sharedMixin"})
public interface AnotherMixin2 {
  String otherField();

  @JsonUnwrapped
  SharedMixin getSharedMixin();

  @JsonIgnore()
  String getName();
}
```

I also tried using "@JsonIgnoreProperties({"name"})" but neither it worked, looks like the property still there when serializing but with an empty value.

Please notice that i can not use @JsonIgnore() inside the SharedMixin because it will ignore the field in all the classes that use it and they are multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Bug in Jackson's library, @JsonUnwrapped and @JsonIgnoreProperties does not work very well together.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

True, `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties` do not work with `@JsonUnwrapped` properly, but placing `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on the field itself helped at least with regular serializing, without mixins:

[How to ignore specific sub-field of an unwrapped field (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458153/how-to-ignore-specific-sub-field-of-an-unwrapped-field-csv)